# Call stored procedure from LINQ (with dbcontext)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

Hello everybody
With EF4, i can map a EDMX function (with "update model from database" and add a stored procedure from the list) to a linq method by using a small snippet like this

```
[EdmFunction("MYPROJECT.Store", "Foo")]
public Decimal Foo(Int32 Id)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("Not direct access possible, use with E-SQL or LINQ");
}
```

But this seems not working with EF 4.1

I see that stored procedures don't work with Code First.
I'm using DbContext, is it normal that i can't do that ?

If yes, how can i make my stored procedures working ?

Thank's by advance :-)

Comment: Use database-first or model-first approaches. Unfortunately, that seems to be the only option for now :-(

Comment: The question is maybe stupid but, i created edmx from database and add dbcontext code generation. I'm database first, right ?

Comment: Yes, but the `DbContext` is a code-first thing - so you seem to have an odd mixture of database-first and code-first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only EDMX related feature and you can't use it with DbContext API code first / fluent API without EDMX. Btw. you mean SQL function and not stored procedure because imported stored procedure results in function import and cannot be called in Linq query. Methods marked with `EdmFunction` states either for imported SQL functions and model defined functions.

Yes I know, SQL functions appears under the stored procedures branch in the import wizard but that is just "feature" of EDMX designer.

Because you are using database-first with DbContext API and EDMX file you should be able to use `EdmFunction` without any problem. I just tested it. The problem probably is that your proxy method marked with `EdmFunction` attribute is not static - it must be static.

Comment: thank's for your reply. I tried to make a new project with the same structure : one edmx file (updated with tables a udf function from sql server db), a dbcontext and a proxy method declared as static with the name of the udf. When i call this method from linq, this is the proxy method who is called (i get an exception). If you tried and succeeded in my problem, can you give me a code snippet ? Thank's by advance :)

Comment: And what exception did you get? Also did you try the same function with ObjectContext API? I don't have the code on my work laptop.

Comment: I get this one :     throw new NotSupportedException("Not direct access possible, use with E-SQL or LINQ");
Just to test, i removed the EdmFunction line, and all works like this one serve to anything. Yeah, i tried with an objectcontext and all works fine

Comment: In such case you are not calling the method in linq-to-entities but in linq-to-objects.

Comment: Sure this must throw exeption because it is not linq query. This must throw exception in `ObjectContext` as well. Method again is not static and it is not used as a fucntion in linq query. EdmFunction is not stored procedure, function must be part of full linq query.

Comment: OMG, i just realized than the good data type to use of the proxy class is not decimal, but double... so 
        [EdmFunction("YoannTestsModel.Store", "add_taxes")]
        public static Double add_taxes(Double value)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Not direct access possible, use with E-SQL or LINQ");
        }
will work with a full linq query like this.
query2 = from p in context.Articles select YoannTestsEntities.add_taxes(12) ;

This time, i think i'm good, i really appreciate your help ! Thank you so much !